# Optimization Problem Libraries

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, nonlinear-programming, test-instances, problem-library

Can someone please make a list of optimization problem libraries so that the community can add to and refine it?

I know a few off the top of my head.

Comment: I have accepted the answer by @Marcus Ritt . But this should be a living question, for which people should continue to add and update library references if they know of any.

Comment: Based on all the answers coming in, we really did need a library of libraries.

Comment: I made a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ekhoda/optimization_problem_libraries) and categorized and added all of these references there. I try to keep it up-to-date with the help of the community.

Comment: Why exactly is this not a community wiki?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

- [Quadratic assignment problem](http://anjos.mgi.polymtl.ca/qaplib)
- [Vehicle routing problem](http://www.bernabe.dorronsoro.es/vrp) also at [HEC](http://neumann.hec.ca/chairedistributique/data)
- [Traveling salesman](http://elib.zib.de/pub/mp-testdata/tsp/tsplib/tsplib.html)
- [Graph partitioning](http://chriswalshaw.co.uk)
- [Quantified Boolean formulas](http://www.qbflib.org)
- [Constraint solvers](http://www.csplib.org)
- [Shortest paths](http://users.diag.uniroma1.it/challenge9/download.shtml)
- [Mixed integer programming](http://miplib.zib.de)
- [Train timetabling](http://ttplib.zib.de)
- [Set covering and packing](http://sites.nlsde.buaa.edu.cn/%7Ekexu/benchmarks/set-benchmarks.htm)
- [Beasley's OR library with many problems](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/%7Emastjjb/jeb/orlib/scpinfo.html)
- [Maximum clique, Maximum independent set, minimum vertex cover, vertex coloring](http://sites.nlsde.buaa.edu.cn/%7Ekexu/benchmarks/graph-benchmarks.htm)
- [Instances for flowshop and routing problems](http://soa.iti.es/instancias-problemas)
- [Graph coloring](https://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/COLOR/instances.html)
- [Binary quadratic programming and Maximum cut](http://biqmac.uni-klu.ac.at/biqmaclib.html)
- [Packing](http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/alg/packlib/instances.shtml)
- [Job shop scheduling](http://optimizizer.com/TA.php)
- [Project scheduling](http://www.om-db.wi.tum.de/psplib/main.html) also at [Ghent](http://solutionsupdate.ugent.be/index.php/)
- [Orienteering](https://www.mech.kuleuven.be/en/cib/op) also [here](https://unicen.smu.edu.sg/oplib-orienteering-problem-library)
- [Capacitated location routing](https://www.coga.tu-berlin.de/v_menue/download_media/clrlib)
- [Bilevel programming](http://basblsolver.github.io/BASBLib/)
- [Steiner trees](http://steinlib.zib.de//steinlib.php)
- [Bin packing](https://www2.wiwi.uni-jena.de/Entscheidung/binpp/index.htm)
- [Frequency assignment](http://fap.zib.de/problems/)
- [General mixed-integer quadratically constrained problems](http://cedric.cnam.fr/%7Elamberta/Library/iqcp_miqcp.html)
- [Prize collecting Steiner tree](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/ivana.ljubic/research/pcstp/)
- [Wireless localization](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecid/Problem-instances/Wireless-Localization/)
- [Maritime transportation planning problem](https://mirplib.scl.gatech.edu/)
- [Stochastic server location problem](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Esahmed/siplib/sslp/sslp.html)
- [Multi-objective linear optimization](https://voptsolver.github.io/vOptLib/)
- [Mixed integer and continuous nonlinear programming](http://www.minlplib.org/)
- [Bin packing, quadratic assigment, cutting stock, vehicle routing](http://perso.prism.uvsq.fr/%7Eblec/index.php?p=./rech/oc&lang=en)
- [Pickup and delivery problems](http://hhperez.webs.ull.es/PDsite/)
- [Traveling Umpire problem](http://benchmark.gent.cs.kuleuven.be/tup/en/)
- [Uncapacitated facility location](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d1/projects/benchmarks/UflLib/)
- [Flow shop scheduling](http://mistic.heig-vd.ch/taillard/problemes.dir/ordonnancement.dir/ordonnancement.html)
- [Employee shift scheduling](http://www.schedulingbenchmarks.org/)
- [Discrete location problems](http://math.nsc.ru/AP/benchmarks/english.html)

Comment: Wow. That's a lot.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a start. Please add to this.

- **BOLIB: Bilevel Optimization LIBrary of Test Problems** https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/436854/1/BOLIBver2.pdf
- **CBLIB: The Conic Benchmark Library**: http://cblib.zib.de/ . Twitter at https://twitter.com/cblibtw
- **Collection of solved Pyomo examples**: https://github.com/OptimizationExpert/Pyomo
- **COMPlib: COnstraint Matrix-optimization Problem library** (Nonlinear SDPs,  control system design, and related problems) http://www.complib.de/
- **CSPlib: A problem library for constraint optimization and satisfaction** http://www.csplib.org/
- **CUTEr/st: Constrained and Unconstrained** (nonlinear optimization) **Testing Environment**: http://www.cuter.rl.ac.uk/Problems/mastsif.shtml
- **Global Optimization Test Problems (Hedar list)**: http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/member/student/hedar/Hedar_files/TestGO.htm
- **Global Optimization Test Problems (Neumaier list)**:
  http://arnold-neumaier.at/glopt/test.html
- **Handbook of Test Problems in Local and Global Optimization**:  http://titan.princeton.edu/TestProblems/
- **MIPLIB 2017 – The Mixed Integer Programming Library**: /https://miplib.zib.de/
- **QPLIB: A Library of Quadratic Programming Instances** http://qplib.zib.de/
- **SDPLIB 1.2, A Library of Semidefinite Programming Test Problems** [http://euler.nmt.edu/~brian/sdplib/](http://euler.nmt.edu/%7Ebrian/sdplib/)
- **SIMOPT (Stochastic) Simulation Optimization Library**: https://github.com/simopt-admin/simopt/wiki/Problem-Library  Note: It would be nice if there were more ("real") multivariate constrained problems.
- **Test Instances for Multiobjective Mixed-Integer Nonlinear Optimization** Paper at https://optimization-online.org/2023/03/test-instances-for-multiobjective-mixed-integer-nonlinear-optimization/

Answer (score 14):

Some more libraries:

- Biq Mac Library: a Binary quadratic and max cut Library: http://biqmac.uni-klu.ac.at/biqmaclib.html
- OR Library: a collection of test data sets for a variety of Operations Research problems: http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/info.html
- SIPLIB: a collection of stochastic integer programming problems: https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~sahmed/siplib/
- SteinLib: a collection of Steiner Tree problems: http://steinlib.zib.de/steinlib.php
- TSPLIB: a library of travelling salesman problems: http://elib.zib.de/pub/mp-testdata/tsp/tsplib/tsplib.html

Answer (score 13):

Some other libraries (mainly for MINLP) are:

1. [MINLP-Lib](http://www.minlplib.org/instances.html).
2. [PrincetonLib](http://titan.princeton.edu/TestProblems).

Answer (score 11):

Some more:

- [Atamturk datasets](https://atamturk.ieor.berkeley.edu/data/) on fixed-charge flow, lot sizing, mixed-integer knapsack, and more
- [Combinatorial Auction Test Suite (CATS)](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kevinlb/CATS/)
- [National Traveling Salesman Problems](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/countries.html)
- [VLSI data sets](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/vlsi/): Another collection of 102 TSP instances
- [GiC Data Sets](https://sites.google.com/site/gciports/)

---

**Update**: I made a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ekhoda/optimization_problem_libraries) and added all of these references. there.

Answer (score 10):

Some libraries for stochastic programming test problems may be found in

[Jeff Linderoth, Alex Shapiro, and Stephen Wright (2002)](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~swright/stochastic/sampling/)

[POSTS: A (PO)rtable (S)tochastic programming (T)est (S)et](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~jrbirge/html/dholmes/post.html) (Derek Holmes and John Birge)

[Test-Problem Collection for Stochastic Linear Programming](https://www4.uwsp.edu/math/afelt/slptestset/download.html) (Andy Felt)

[SIPLIB: A (S)tochastic (I)nteger (P)rogramming Test Problem (LIB)rary](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~sahmed/siplib/) (Shabbir Ahmed et al.)

[WATSON pension fund management test problems](http://vlsicad.eecs.umich.edu/BK/Slots/cache/www-cfr.jims.cam.ac.uk/research/stprog.html)

[cORe: (c)omputational (O)perations (R)esearch (e)xchange](https://core.isrd.isi.edu/chaise/recordset/#1/Core:Instance@sort(RCT::desc::,RID)) (Suvrajeet Sen)

Comment: added them to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ekhoda/optimization_problem_libraries)

Answer (score 8):

Would these be helpful?

1) OptaPlanner examples [problem definitions](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#examplesOverview) and [data sets](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/data)

- *Original problems*: cloud balancing, dinner party, tennis club scheduling, meeting scheduling, task assigning, investment portfolio optimization, conference scheduling, rock tour, flight crew scheduling
- *Problems defined by academic challenges and others*: tsp, course scheduling (ITC 2007), machine reassignment (ROADEF 2012), vrp, project job scheduling, hospital bed planning, exam timetabling (ITC 2007), nurse rostering, traveling tournament, cheap time scheduling, coach shuttle gathering

2) For VRP and variants, I'd argue that [VRP-REP](http://www.vrp-rep.org/) is the canonical place to find high-quality datasets.

Answer (score 1):

There is also:

- [GasLib](http://gaslib.zib.de/), with gas network instances based on perturbed real-world data.