# Supply Chain Public Data Repository

Tags: online-resources, data, supply-chain

I was wondering if there is any repository of datasets for supply chain problems. For example, the [UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php) contains datasets for ML, and [MIPLIB](https://miplib.zib.de/) is used as a benchmark for MIP and IP problems. But I cannot find a similar dataset for general supply chain problems. Can you please direct me to such a repository, if one exists?

Note that the lists in [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/244/optimization-problem-libraries) question, are mostly open-source libraries, not data-sets, although few of them include data-sets too. [UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php) is just a set of data-sets, and its main point is that it is a single web-site of Machine Learning data-set collection. You can just search there to find what you need.

Comment: Have you checked this [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/244/optimization-problem-libraries). There is a list of optimization libraries (including the MIPLIB) you mentioned.

Comment: @EhsanK Those are mostly open-source libraries, not data-sets, although few of them include data-sets too. http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php is just a set of data-sets, and its main point is that it is a single web-site of Machine Learning data-set collection. You can just search there to find what you need.

Comment: In that case, I think you can make your comment as an edit to your post, mention that your question is different from the one I linked above (so, you won't be flagged as asking a duplicate question)

Comment: Questions, lists, opinions, etc. on OR resources, GOOD!!  Generic SE guidelines notwithstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is any repository of datasets for supply chain problems?

- [Global Garment Supply Chain Data](https://old.datahub.io/dataset/global-garment-supply-chain-data) - A collection of import data from various retailers - Last updated: October 19, 2013, 10:23 AM (UTC-07:00)
  [Note: The website Datahub has [11,591 other datasets](https://old.datahub.io/dataset).]
- USAID - [Supply Chain Shipment Pricing Data](https://www.usaid.gov/data/dataset/0162a542-4f2e-4fe2-ad5d-8f6ed2344056)

  > This data set provides supply chain health commodity shipment and pricing data. Specifically, the data set identifies Antiretroviral (ARV) and HIV lab shipments to supported countries. In addition, the data set provides the commodity pricing and associated supply chain expenses necessary to move the commodities to countries for use. The dataset has similar fields to the Global Fund's Price, Quality and Reporting (PQR) data. PEPFAR and the Global Fund represent the two largest procurers of HIV health commodities. This dataset, when analyzed in conjunction with the PQR data, provides a more complete picture of global spending on specific health commodities. The data are particularly valuable for understanding ranges and trends in pricing as well as volumes delivered by country.
- The article "[Data Set—Real-World Multiechelon Supply Chains Used for Inventory Optimization](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/msom.1070.0176)" (Dec 11 2007), by Sean P. Willems has this supplemental material: "[Real-World Multi-Echelon Supply Chains Used for Inventory Optimization: Online Appendix](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/suppl/10.1287/msom.1070.0176)" (Feb 8 2007), by Sean P. Willems:

  > Supplemental Material
  >   [msom.1070.0176-sm-data_set.pdf](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/suppl/10.1287/msom.1070.0176/suppl_file/msom.1070.0176-sm-data_set.pdf) (124 KB)
  >   [msom.1070.0176-sm-datainaccess.zip](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/suppl/10.1287/msom.1070.0176/suppl_file/msom.1070.0176-sm-datainaccess.zip) (548 KB)
  >   [msom.1070.0176-sm-datainexcel.zip](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/suppl/10.1287/msom.1070.0176/suppl_file/msom.1070.0176-sm-datainexcel.zip) (2 MB)
  >   [msom.1070.0176-sm-datainxml.zip](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/suppl/10.1287/msom.1070.0176/suppl_file/msom.1070.0176-sm-datainxml.zip) (432 KB)
  >   [Additional](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Hello_everyone_Im_looking_for_a_Dataset_of_any_kind_in_Supply_Chain_Management_SCM_Preferably_a_dataset_on_Supply_Chain_Risks_Thanks_Max) Dataset: [MSOM-06-038-R2 Data Set in Excel.xls - Enhanced.zip](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Maxwell_Taylor/post/Hello_everyone_Im_looking_for_a_Dataset_of_any_kind_in_Supply_Chain_Management_SCM_Preferably_a_dataset_on_Supply_Chain_Risks_Thanks_Max/attachment/59d64b3479197b80779a550e/AS%3A479066462658560%401491229753646/download/MSOM-06-038-R2+Data+Set+in+Excel.xls+-+Enhanced.zip) (2.55 MB)
  >
  > This data set describes 38 multi-echelon supply chains that have been implemented in practice. These chains exhibit special structure that can be used to inform and test analytical models. Although the data were not collected with the intention of econometric analysis, it is possible that they could be useful in an empirical study. The data described in this paper are publicly available at the journal’s web site http://www.msom.org.

  [Note: The Manufacturing and Service Operations Management Society's new URL is: https://msomsociety.org/ - I don't see this information available on their new website, nor is it [indexed](https://www.google.com/search?q=msom.1070.0176-sm-datainaccess.zip%20msom.1070.0176-sm-datainexcel.zip%20msom.1070.0176-sm-datainxml.zip&filter=0&biw=980&bih=1666) for availability elsewhere.]

  > In particular, each chain contains the exact supply chain network created by the contributor plus the exact characterization of leadtimes at every stage in the supply chain plus realistic yet disguised values for all the supply chain’s data. A secondary use of this data might be to support empirical research into the nature of the supply chains created. The data, available in Microsoft Access, Microsoft Excel and XML formats, are open to all researchers as long as the researcher is willing to cite Willems (2007) as the source. Section 2 presents background information for the chains and Section 3 presents some observations to place the data in context.
- Data.gov offers [1 public dataset](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=supply-chain)

  > [NYSERDA New York Offshore Wind Supply Chain Dataset](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/nyserda-new-york-offshore-wind-supply-chain-dataset)
  >   Metadata Updated: June 14, 2019
  >
  > The dataset contains contact and description information for local supply chain organizations, offshore wind developers, and original equipment manufacturers that provide goods and services to support New York State’s offshore wind industry. The dataset will benefit local suppliers and the offshore wind industry in New York State.
- Huge [list of public datasets](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public) on Quora.
- [OpenML](https://www.openml.org/search?q=supply%20chain&type=data) has a couple of supply chain databases:

  [scm1d](https://www.openml.org/d/41485) & [scm20d](https://www.openml.org/d/41486) - The Supply Chain Management datasets are derived from the Trading Agent Competition in Supply Chain Management (TAC SCM) tournament from 2010. The precise methods for data preprocessing and normalization are described in detail by Groves and Gini (2011).
- Another place to ask is on our [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) beta site. It's good practice when asking the same question on more than one site to include links to your other identical questions.

Answer (score 8):

- Éric Taillard publishes problem sets for flow shop, job shop and open shop scheduling (from one of his papers) at http://mistic.heig-vd.ch/taillard/problemes.dir/ordonnancement.dir/ordonnancement.html.
- Oleg Shylo publishes job shop problem sets from Demirkol et al., as well as best known solutions to both the Taillard and Demirkol problems, at http://optimizizer.com/jobshop.php.
- The data sets from an old paper I coauthored (scheduling a single machine to minimize tardiness with sequence-dependent setups) are available on my web site at https://msu.edu/~rubin/research/c_or_data/. (Note for posterity: that site is scheduled to be eliminated in the next year or so, and I do not yet know where the data will end up.)