# Cellular Automata and MIP Resource Repository?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cellular-automata

Apologies if this is not an appropriate question for the SE, however, considering that it is in beta testing it might be worthwhile. Note that "Cellular Automata" is not yet a tag, so perhaps there is some use in this post...

I am studying invasive species management and often the problems focus on using techniques from OR such as MIP to answer the problems. Another layer of complexity in these papers is that they incorporate their problems into something called a "cellular automata" framework, however, I have no experience with either modelling an MIP problem or cellular automata problem, let along both combined.

So I am hoping that perhaps the community may be able to put together a useful information repository on optimization problems within the context of cellular automata. Ideally, people in the future who have similar problems might find this if they search for cellular automata. Again, apologies if this is not appropriate for the forum.

Comment: Since this is a question about the OR.SE **site**, and not **about OR**, it belongs on [meta](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/). However, even there you might find that people think creating an information repository on OR and cellular automata is not really in scope (but others might disagree). On the other hand, if you have a *specific* question about how to model cellular automata (or anything else!) using OR, then I think it will be welcome here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [meta](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Meta, schmeta. Leave it here. Perhaps try to fix up the question somewhat.

Comment: @MarkLStone fix it up how? It’s a perfectly fine question, it just belongs on meta, not here. (IMO.)

Comment: Not a problem. I wasn't aware about the meta SE (still new to SE in general). I did find a question about building a problem repository in OR that had many people contribute, so I thought that perhaps this was also something worthwhile to include. The problem I have is knowing how to ask the appropriate question, which is why I thought seeing examples of such problems would help inform future questions.

Comment: @D.Gray - Perhaps you could rewrite the 3rd paragraph: "What are key references on optimization problems within the context of cellular automata?" Then the answers to the question would become a mini-repository - does that capture what you're trying to ask?

Comment: I thought you meant a repository in the sense of some kind of standalone site. If you’re suggesting a single post with multiple links (e.g., [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/244/optimization-problem-libraries)) then I like @E.Tucker’s suggestion. In general the advice on SE is, don’t ask if you can ask, just ask. So I’d say just ask the question you want to ask, or, if you want to discuss it further, ask on meta.