# Is there a library of infeasible MINLP problems?

Tags: minlp, feasible-points, test-instances, problem-library

We have a number of test libraries to test solver performance like MINLPLIB, QPLIB, etc., but the problems in all libraries I know are overwhelmingly on the feasible side.

Is there a library to test a solver's ability to prove infeasibility?

Comment: To be interesting, include models for which feasibility is unknown.  For instance, for MILP, see https://twitter.com/Ed_Klotz/status/1186091930582704129 .

Comment: here is a long list of NLP and MINLP test problems (https://www.minlp.com/nlp-and-minlp-test-problems) you may find some test problems for infeasible ones as well.

Comment: For any feasible library instance with objective function $f(x)$ that we are maximizing and a known optimal objective value $o$, you could add a constraint $f(x) \ge o+1$ to get an infeasible problem instance. So my guess is that you could pretty easily build such a library from existing ones.

Comment: @josliber For an MINLP wouldn't that just set the global optimum to another local optimum of the original problem?

Comment: @nikaza Presumably josliber intends $\alpha$ to be the global **maximum** objective value, so adding the stated constraint renders the problem infeasible. Perhaps you read it as minimum, not maximum. .... While these would be infeasible problems, hopefully they would only be a part of an infeasible problem library, because all the infeasibilities would be of the same type, due to a single inequality involving the objective function.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Ah yes, I missed the maximization part, you are right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the following weblink:

https://www.minlp.com/nlp-and-minlp-test-problems

Comment: Do you know which and how many  of these within each library are infeasible?  Anyhow, you should also add this to https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/244/optimization-problem-libraries .