# Asymmetric vehicle routing benchmark instances

Tags: vehicle-routing

Is there a standard set of asymmetric capacitated vehicle routing problem (ACVRP) benchmark instances similar to CVRP  (http://vrp.galgos.inf.puc-rio.br/index.php/en/)?

The only thing I found were a few (easy) instances from Fischetti, et al. (1994) here:
http://or.dei.unibo.it/library/vrplib-vehicle-routing-problem-library

Comment: Have you checked everything at https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/244/optimization-problem-libraries/245 ? In any event, be sure to add there anything you find.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at VRP REP's, filtered on ACVRP datasets.

That listing includes [my "Belgium" VRP datasets on on VRP REP](http://www.vrp-rep.org/datasets/item/2017-0001.html) (the most popular download on VRP REP) which contain asymmetric CVRP datasets. Look for the **road-km** and **road-time** variants in the files of that zip. The "air" variants are symmetric. It has variants with one depot and variants with multiple depots. Each variant has variants with 50 locations up to 2750 locations.