# Is there a Bin Packing Library similar to TSPLIB?

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, knapsack

I have concluded there is not, or if there is it's not openly published?

I am trying to identify if there are "top solutions/formulations" for the 3d BPP. Looking to apply in a parcel packing context.

Update: The problem is parcel packing, given a known set of items, their weights and dimensions, and a fixed set of possible boxes(different sizes allowed). I recognize now this is a narrow interpretation. I'm interested in any solution to this problem(it does not necessarily need to be optimizations, or be formulated in 3d, etc.) I'll consolidate any responses/findings I see posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

BPPLIB – A Bin Packing Problem Library:
http://or.dei.unibo.it/library/bpplib

Comment: You should add this (plus whatever else) as an answer at "Optimization Problem Libraries"  https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/244/optimization-problem-libraries

Comment: Let's note that it's only for 1D BPP

Comment: BPPLIB contains a lot of instances for Bin Packing and Cutting Stock problems. It also gives an extensive survey of techniques to solve these problems, with links to papers and codes. We use it a lot to benchmark: https://www.localsolver.com/benchmarkbpp.html. Nevertheless, as @fontanf pointed out, this is limited to 1D bin packing.

Answer (score 2):

For the 2D and 3D variant you can find multiple instances as well as instance generators here:

- https://github.com/Oscar-Oliveira/OR-Datasets/tree/master/Cutting-and-Packing
- https://www.euro-online.org/websites/esicup/data-sets/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a heuristic check [this](https://github.com/skjolber/3d-bin-container-packing) out. The limitation is that it is written in java.